# Get Latest blocks with bitcoind on Ubuntu

Tags: bitcoind, block

The total `blockcount` on my machine is not increasing. I have tried doing a `bitcoind -reindex -daemon`, but it didn't ultimately increase the number of blocks.

Attaching machine and `bitciond` information below.

Operating System:

```
my_machine ~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Bitcoin daemon:

```
my_machine ~ $ bitcoind getinfo
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 322082,
    "timeoffset" : 1,
    "connections" : 8,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 29829733124.04041672,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1422374797,
    "keypoolsize" : 100,
    "unlocked_until" : 0,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : "Warning: The network does not appear to fully agree! Some miners appear to be experiencing issues."
}
```

UPDATE: Per the issue explained here: http://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/mailman/message/33222029/, it appears that OpenSSL is the issue.  I tried to rectify the latest block being stuck at 322082 by doing the following

```
git clone -b 0.9 https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin.git bitcoin-0.9
cd bitcoin-0.9
./autogen.sh
cd src
./configure
./configure --with-incompatible-bdb
make
make check
stop bitcoind
bitcoind -daemon -server -reindex
```

I then waited for the reindex to finish but I still have the same problem. Am I doing something wrong? How can I test that I have the right version of OpenSSL required?

Comment: What does the `debug.log` say? You may locate it in the same folder as wallet.dat - `%APPDATA%\Bitcoin`

Comment: db.log posted here: http://pastebin.com/Bcw66V5C

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/5645) GitHub discussion it turns out that the problem is caused by OpenSSL moving to `0.9.4.0 binaries` should resolve your issue.

Gregory Maxwell

> The incompatibility is due to the OpenSSL update changing the
>   behavior of ECDSA validation to reject any signature which is
>   not encoded in a very rigid manner.  This was a result of
>   OpenSSL's change for CVE-2014-8275 "Certificate fingerprints
>   can be modified".
>
> While for most applications it is generally acceptable to eagerly
>   reject some signatures, Bitcoin is a consensus system where all
>   participants must generally agree on the exact validity or
>   invalidity of the input data.  In a sense, consistency is more
>   important than "correctness".

Comment: Ahh, I think you're right that OpenSSL is the issue. Per the guidance here http://sourceforge.net/p/bitcoin/mailman/message/33222029/, I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer pointed doubt at the "9.4 SHOULD resolve your issue" answer above. That appears to have been suggested by someone who hasn't actually tried it. I, however, have tried it... 
I have the the same OS version and the same problem as the OP. He didn't mention changing openssl, so probably has the same one as me, too (as supplied/updated with 14.04). 0.9.4 didn't work.
I find it a bit odd that you delete an answer saying that a suggested fix doesn't work, but leave the unverified fix up. 
I'd love to find a real answer too, it takes me nearly two weeks to reindex and find out that a suggested fix doesn't work, maybe other people would like to know it didn't work on another 14.04 system?
No doubt this will get deleted too as it isn't answer.
I have the patched 1.01f

Comment: pictsidhe, I believe your answer was removed because it recommended using a version of openssl that is vulnerable to the heartbleed bug (OpenSSL 1.0.1 through 1.0.1f are vulnerable). In addition, while I agree with you that it is valuable information to know if a proposed solution doesn't work, it would be better if you put a comment on the previous answer rather than submitting in another answer to the question.